# Unable to load PHP5 with a new installation of Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, php5, debian-squeeze

`Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so: undefined symbol: unixd_config`

I spent the last hour or so googling, and it seems that I have to create a new PHP5 after installing my new Apache (2.4.2). Debian didn't have Apache 2.4.2 and it's a requirement I was given. I still have the PHP 5.4.4 from Debian wheezy repository. I tried including it in the new Apache 2.4.2 that I installed, but it throws the error you see above. Is there a way to "reglue" everything? I was going to just install a fresh PHP, but I ran into some errors on `./configure`, so I wanted to see if there were easier ways before I spend more time on installing a new copy.

Answer (score 1):

You could compile PHP yourself

Get the source with

```
apt-get source php5
```

then get the dependencies

```
apt-get build-dep php5
```

Then a it might work.

Comment: (it's only going to work if you've got the apxs binary for the version of apache you've got installed - and apache is compiled with mod_so - see the apxs man page for more details)